Filtering regex from bash variable containing text
I have variable in bash:
$ users_="a1 .localhost a2 a3 .localhost a4"

I'd like to read into bash array all phrases startking with 'a' and ending with '.localhost', which in this case will be:
"a1 .localhost"
"a3 .localhost"

The regex should be I think a[0-9]+\s\.localhost or ^a[0-9]+\s\.localhost$ (I'm not sure). The a2 and a4 prases should be ommited.
So, how to achieve it?
What i was trying is:
$ $users_ | grep '^a[0-9]+\s\.localhost$'
But it throws me an error.
Thanks for replies.
Mike.

In [tag:bash], use grep '^a[0-9]+\s\.localhost$' <<<"$users_", in POSIX shell, use echo "$users_" | grep '^a[0-9]+\s\.localhost$'.

Is it correct you want to preserve spaces in the output as in "a1 .localhost" ?  When stating "it throws me an error", then include the error message.

Regarding "But it throws me an error." - any time you want anyone to help you with any kind of error, please tell them what the error message is so they can help you with that without needing to guess.

The reason why I did not paste the error message, was that it was written in Polish Language and relied on my server environment. Code was not working, because bash was returning formated text (colored) with extra white chars, which was not able to filter. I just took the output and processed it in PHP processor, which done the job. Thanks.

Solution :
You can use mapfile and a for loop to write the lines.
users_="a1 .localhost a2 a3 .localhost a4"

mapfile -t users_array < <(echo "$users_" | grep -Eo 'a[0-9]+\s\.localhost')

for user in "${users_array[@]}"; do
    echo "$user"
done

Expected result :
When you run the ./your_file.bash, you get:
a1 .localhost
a3 .localhost

Elements a2 and a4 are ignored because they do not correspond to the desired format.

Output of your script doesn't match the expected result. The whole script is simply equivalent to grep -Eo 'a[0-9]+\s\.localhost' <<< "a1 .localhost a2 a3 .localhost a4"

@M.NejatAydin Ah yes I made a small error in the post for the rendering

And mapfile, for loop, echo? What are they good for?

You don't need to use grep, bash can match regular expressions, too:
#! /bin/bash
users_="a1 .localhost a2 a3 .localhost a4"
u=$users_
while [[ $u =~ a[0-9][[:space:]]+\.localhost ]] ; do
    s=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}  # Store the matching part in $s.
    u=${u#*"$s"}          # Remove everything up to the match.
    printf '<%s>\n' "$s"
done

Without running external commands and starting subshells, it's also surprisingly fast, which is an advantage if you need to run it many times.

users_="a1 .localhost a2 a3 .localhost a4"

matches=($(echo "$users_" | grep -oE 'a[0-9]+ \.localhost'))

for match in "${matches[@]}"; do
  echo "$match"
done


This splits each match on whitespace, i.e. it outputs 4 lines instead of 2.
